# Evaluating specific array value using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 160 inputs in my page. I want to add every 8 inputs and output it elsewhere. Instead of manually using

```
var total1 = inputVals[0] + inputVals[1] + inputVals[2] + inputVals[3] + inputVals[4] + inputVals[5] + inputVals[6] + inputVals[7] + inputVals[8];
```

I want a function with which you can just specify the starting and ending index like addarray(9, 17) and it will add all the values between and will return it. I prefer the function to be in javascript but jquery is OK.

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward with a loop

Comment: "I want" is not a question. SO is not here to just do it for you. Show your attempts, if any, or describe exactly what you're stuck with and someone will _help_ you

Comment: loops thats the answer thank you. Sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `<input>` elements defined as:

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" />
<input type="text" class="myInput" />
<input type="text" class="myInput" />
...
```

You can create a method that does the job with the help of jQuery:

```
function add(start, end) {
    var total = 0;
    $(".myInput").slice(start, end).each(function() {
        total += +this.value;
    });
    return total;
}
```

The same method in pure JavaScript will look like:

```
function add(start, end) {
    var total = 0,
        inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("myInput");

    for (var i = start; i < Math.min(end, inputs.length); i++) [
        total += +inputs[i].value;
    });
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function calcTotal(index) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        total += inputVals[index + i];
    }
    return total;
}
var total1 = calcTotal(0);
```

OR

```
function calcRangeTotal(index, count) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        total += inputVals[index + i];
    }
    return total;
}
var total1 = calcRangeTotal(0, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
var calculate = function() {
    var sum=0;
    $("input").each(function(index,element){
        sum+=Number($(element).val());
    });
    alert(sum);
};

$(function(){
    $("button").on("click",calculate);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8HR6/) is th jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;

function caluculate(firstIndex,secondIndex){

   for(var i=one;i<secondIndex;i+=8)
     sum=parseInt(sum+inputVals[i]);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addarray($start,$end) {
   var total = 0;
   for(var i = $start; i < $end; i++)
       total += inputVals[i];
   return total;
}

var myTotal = addarray(9,17);
```